# Out putting an ACF nested repeater within a foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach, nested, repeater, advanced-custom-fields

I have a Food/Drinks menu on a website which the owner can fill-in the backend using an ACF nested repeater:

Level 1. section_container (parent repeater)
Level 2. section_heading (text field) sub_section_container (sub repeater)
Level 3. sub_section_heading (text field) food_item (sub sub repeater)
Level 4. item_name (text) item_description (text) price (text)

Each time a new parent repeater is created this contents should be placed within a sequential div called "section_0x" (the 'x' increases 1 with each addition). The content of this div will be visible in the tab content area with the calls 'tabcontent'.

In other words, the entire content of section_container (parent repeater) and it's sub fields should be wrapped in div called 'section_01' then and subsequent parent repeaters with be placed in sequential divs 'section_02' , 'section_03' etc., etc.

The Tab heading is also added automatically using the sub_field "section_heading". This is working correctly - so each time a parent repeater is created a new tabbed section is created on the front end and the heading is outputted.

However I'm having trouble outputting the entire contents of the nested repeater within the tabbed content area.

```
            <?php
            /**
             * Template part for displaying the food menu
             *
             * @package GL_Apollo
             */

            ?>

            <script>

            function openSection(evt, sectionName) {
                // Declare all variables
                var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
                    // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
                    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
                        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
                            tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
                        }
                            // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
                            tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
                            for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
                                tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
                            }
                    // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
                    document.getElementById(sectionName).style.display = "block";
                    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
            }
            </script>

            <div class="food-menu-container">
                <div class="menu-title"><?php the_field('menu_title'); ?> </div>
            <!-- Tab links -->
            <div class="food-menu-tab-container">
                <div class="tab">
                <?php 
                    $counter_tab = 1;
                    if( have_rows('section_container') ) :
                    while( have_rows('section_container') ): the_row();
                    $section_name = array( get_sub_field('section_heading') ); 
                    foreach ($section_name as $section_names) {?>
                <button class="tablinks" onclick="openSection(event, 'section_0<?php echo $counter_tab; ?>')">
                    <?php echo $section_names; ?>
                </button>
                <?php $counter_tab++; // increment before foreach ends
                    }
                    endwhile;
                    endif;
                    wp_reset_postdata();
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Food content -->
                    <div class="menu-section-container">
                        <?php
                            $counter = 1;
                            // check if the repeater field has rows of data
                            if( have_rows('section_container') ):
                            // loop through the rows of data
                            while ( have_rows('section_container') ) : the_row();
                                    $section_container = get_field('section_container');
                                if( have_rows('sub_section_container') ):
                                // loop through the rows of data
                                while ( have_rows('sub_section_container') ) : the_row();
                                    $sub_section_container = get_field('sub_section_container');
                                    $sub_head = get_sub_field('sub_section_heading');
                                    if( have_rows('food_item') ):
                                    // loop through the rows of data
                                    while ( have_rows('food_item') ) : the_row();
                                            $item = get_sub_field('item_name');
                                            $price = get_sub_field('price');
                                            $description = get_sub_field('item_description');
                                        $menu_content = array (
                                            "<div>$section_container</div>" . "<div>$sub_section_container</div>" . "<div class='sub_head'>$sub_head</div>" . "<div class='item'>$item</div>" . "<div class='price'>$price</div>" . "<div class='description'>$description</div>"
                                        );                          
                                            foreach ($menu_content as $menu_contents); { ?>
                                                <div id="section_0<?php echo $counter; ?>" class="tabcontent">
                                                    <?php echo($menu_contents) ?>
                                                </div>
                                        <?php $counter++; // increment before foreach ends
                                        }
                                    endwhile;
                                    endif;
                                endwhile;
                                endif;
                            endwhile;
                            endif;

                    echo '<pre>';
                        var_dump( $menu_contents );
                    echo '</pre>';?>

                    </div> <!-- section -->
            </div> <!-- menu-section-container -->

            <span class="btn" data-glf-cuid="0c1de6b2-1ca9-4202-b790-3cd5a62af2b3" data-glf-ruid="9e6118c3-d144-4511-973e-d7d7f7418e1a" ><?php the_field('order_button'); ?></span> 
            <script src="https://www.fbgcdn.com/widget/js/ewm2.js" deferasync ></script>

            </div> <!-- food-menu-container -->
```

Comment: other than your string conversion - what is wrong with your version 2_1?

Comment: http://apollo.crunchyfrogtestsite.com/home-2_1/

Comment: @stender it’s outputting level 3 and 4 in a div section_01 not the entire parent repeater. All of the fields mentioned above should be contained within section_01 this will be the first tab contents (let’s say Starter) then if that whole block of fields are repeated -as in another parent row is created, this will be wrapped in div section_02 and will be the second tab contents. Sorry I’m finding it hard to explain what needs to happen. Hence the reposted question.